# drag drop across iFrame using Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I need some controls to work with Drag & Drop across iFrame. the reason i need the functionality in an iframe is because its a CMS that we are building and the any "absolute" css changes in the "editing page" will impact the main site as well.

Ive written a angular directive and built a small prototype as well for this and it works perfect as long as its on the same page, but the moment i try to do the same across iframes, it just does not works. even registering the droppbale from the iFrame page does not shows up in console (when trying to log through directive).

its a 1 pager code and available for viewing here - `http://78.110.163.229/angDnd/outer.html`

any guidance / advice would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the `iframe`'s body is never actually made `droppable`.
There is this piece of code in the body:

```
$(function () {
    $("#canvas-frame").ready(function (){
        var contents = $("#ifr").contents();
        var ifrBody = contents.find('body');
        //console.log(ifrBody);
        $(ifrBody).attr("dnd-droppable","true");
    })
});
```

(Some of) the problems with it are the following:

1. I don't see any `#canvas-frame` element.
2. Even if there were one such element, the `dnd-droppable` attribute is added to the `iframe`'s body **after** angular has parsed the DOM, so it is not taken into account at all.

---

#### Solution:

In your HTML, add a new directive on the `iframe` element:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="inner.html" dnd-droppable-iframe></iframe>
```

In your JS, define the new directive so that it waits for the `iframe` to be loaded, then adds the `dndDroppable` directive to its body element and compile's it, so Angular can "pick it up":

```
dndApp.directive('dndDroppableIframe', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (elem.prop('tagName') !== 'IFRAME') { return; }

            elem.ready(function () {
                var ifrBody = elem.contents().find('body');
                ifrBody.attr('dnd-droppable', '');
                $compile(ifrBody)(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful and definitely a step in the right direction - i am relatively new to Angular and still learning the ropes.  ive now update the code as per your suggestion - however, there is still one small challenge. the elements are not getting dropped directly on iFrame as they are with the on-page div. im now trying to debug this further, if you have any further suggestions on what else am i missing - that would be really helpful.

Comment: Somehow I forgot to wait for the frame to load. Please, try my updated code.

Comment: just tried the same, not working yet. something strange actually - when i drop elements in the onPageDiv, they actually get duplicated on to iFrame body as well. when i drop anything on iFrame, it does not do anything at all. it seems, something is still missing... not sure why but I'm almost at my wit's end - struggling with this for past 2-3 days. really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey, it turned out to be much more of a problem than I initially suspected. Did you have any luck with it. I am still trying to figure it out, but in order for the results (if any) to be useful (to you) I need to know the exact requirements (e.g.: Do you have access in the top-level page and/or the "iframed" one ? What kind of elements are you going to DnD (or all elements) ? Do you also need "inter-iframe" DnD (i.e. from one iframe to the other) ?

Comment: hiya, yes i think ive managed to progress further with it. my requirements 
(1) I will have 1 top level page which will contain a single iFrame within it. both will have the same domain so its not going to be using different URLs and the cross site scripting shoudl not be an issue.
(2) being a CMS system, the elements will be small widgets (div, input boxes, images, etc.) which the user can drag from the toolbox on the right section on the iFrame panel to compose the page and generate HTML in background. its going to be a limited set of elements.

Comment: (3) there is no need to drag from one iFrame to another however there is a need to have the dragging enabled within the iFrame which currently is enabled.

Comment: **Progress:** pls look at the link - it has the updated code, the functionality works to a large extent with one final issue left. the cursor position assumes that the iframe starts from left:0 & top:0 which makes it a bit difficult to position the elements properly for drag & drop both. any ideas how i can manipulate the position when the elements are being dragged across iframe.